# JavaScript libraries along with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, javascript

Apart from jQuery, which other JavaScript libraries support Visual Studio2005/2008 intellisense integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 supports JScript intellisense for anything that has a vsdoc.

See [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/21/vs-2008-javascript-intellisense.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Any javascript library will work with Visual Studio.  If by "integration" you mean "Intellisense", only 2008 supports javascript Intellisense.  Beyond that there isn't much interaction between javascript and VS.

Comment: jQuery is the only library I know of that has prepared a 2008-compatible "hint" file that makes intellisense work.  That same file can be created for any library if someone is willing to invest the time.

Answer (score 1):

Open the jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js file and take a look at the code comments. The Intellisense comes from those markup comments, which many libraries do not supply.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it will only be jQuery (as a library) at the moment. Microsoft have teamed up with the jQuery team as they will be looking to integrate it into the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit and to implement new Ajax server-side helper methods for ASP.NET MVC Framework.